# Error 404 after I rename the folder in wamp/www that caintains the my website

Tags: php, webserver, wamp

The problem is too basic I can't find it anywhere.
I created a website under the folder "test" and can't open the site after I rename it to "test1".
It occurs:
Error 404 - Not Found
We're very sorry, but that page doesn't exist or has been moved.
Please make sure you have the right URL.

Comment: Did you navigate to `/test1/` in your browser as opposed to `/test/`...?

Comment: Did you try restarting the WAMP server, refreshing services, etc.?

Comment: Yes, I did. No luck.

Comment: @bnahin  Yes, I restarted all the services and refreshed the WAMP, cleared the cache of firefox restart it and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough rep to add a comment so adding this as an answer - hopefully it helps.

Did you update the httpd.conf file to reflect your new website root (being test1 rather than test)?  If not, update the file then restart WAMP.

Comment: I opened the httpd.conf file which located at E:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf , but I can't find "test" using the search tool.

Comment: You can get to the httpd.conf file by clicking on the WAMP server icon, then click on Apache and then httpd.conf

Search for 'DocumentRoot'. What's the value there? Also, do you have virtual hosts configured? The document root may be set there if you do...

Comment: This is what I found: 
  #DocumentRoot "e:/wamp/www/"## Each directory to which ....

Comment: How did you get to the site originally?  Did you navigate to http://localhost/test?  Or did you just go straight to http://localhost?

Comment: Also check the conf file in E:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf and see if the DocumentRoot is set in there?

Comment: Yes, I get to the site originally by navigating to localhost/test.

Comment: I only got one search result in the httpd-vhosts.conf it says: # Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.

Comment: Is there a .htaccess file in the test1 folder?

Comment: Yes, I changed all the "test" to "test1" even if I don't know what I was doing. I just tried whatever I can find... http://prntscr.com/7qwr5a

Comment: Looks good.  Did it fix it?  If you're running a Wordpress site you may need to update the settings in Wordpress itself as well.  There's more information on changing directories for Wordpress here https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: It didn't. I'm learning the info on the website you gave me. Thanks a lot!